# % of unknown number when trying to find unknown number

Tags: percentages

I'm working on a spreadsheet for my small real estate business and I'm stuck on a math problem.

I want to find the minimum rent I can charge for a property to still break even. I know the monthly mortgage and all my expenses except 2: vacancy coverage and management fees. These 2 numbers are 5% and 10% of the rent, respectively. The issue is that I'm trying to figure out the rent, but 2 of the numbers I need are contingent on the rent. Here's what I think is right, but it doesn't make sense:

Rent = mortgage + expenses + (15% of rent)

But how do I find the 15% of the rent when that 15% is part of the number?

(I am not looking at profit for this exercise...just my break even point, so my goal is for this to end up being total expenses - rent = 0.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
R = M + E + 0.15R
$$
so
$$
(1-0.15)R = M+E
$$
so
$$
R = \frac{M+E}{0.85}.
$$

Comment: Thanks so much. I was so close...it was the over .85 that I was missing. I super appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer (the checkmark) so the question does not linger on the unanswered queue.